# Django dev server intermittently fails to serve static files

Tags: django, django-dev-server

In my development environment I'm getting intermittent failures for serving static files (js scripts and css). In the error console in Chrome I get 404s. But if I refresh on those items, or visit the URLs directly, they're served up fine.

This is annoying.

Example:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/js/editor/xyz.js?v=1 404 (NOT FOUND)
```

but if I visit that URL directly fine. And if I refresh the page a few times, it will work again.

Any ideas?

Chrome 14.0.835.202

```
Django==1.3
Fabric==1.0.1
Jinja2==2.5.5
PIL==1.1.7
Pygments==1.3.1
South==0.7.3
Sphinx==1.0.5
boto==2.0
chunks==0.1
django-devserver==0.2.1
django-pagination==1.0.7
django-sorting==0.1
django-storages==1.1.3
docutils==0.8
gunicorn==0.12.1
ipython==0.10.1
paramiko==1.7.6
pep8==0.6.1
psycopg2==2.2.2
pycrypto==2.0.1
python-dateutil==1.5
python-memcached==1.45
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Comment: I"m having the same issue. Did you manage figuring out the reason?

Comment: Not yet! Running with --forked seems to work but makes using pdb impossible

Comment: why does your url have "?v=1" ?

Comment: That's just a future-proofing cache-busting thing. It's not used by dev server, just so we can change the URL for the next version.

Comment: please post your settings.py

Comment: Sorry, this was over a year ago. The settings file wasn't particularly exotic.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, even with using django concurent dev server.  Chrome says the request is "Pending" and never completes.

Answer (score 2):

The dev server is single-threaded so if something keeps waiting, it blocks every request.

I usualy work with the [django concurent dev server](https://github.com/ashchristopher/django-concurrent-server) which is multi-threaded and works much better. Also it is very fast and easy to setup ;)

Comment: This has stopped happening for me, it is frustrating. I have not updated Django on the project... strange.

Comment: @Thomas: maybe chrome do something special? It probably should be confirmed with other browsers.

Comment: @Joe: Have you 404 in your django runserver console log? You may also increase debugging level and then check if a problems appears again.

Answer (score -1):

it might depends on your setup.
what did you do for the static? what's the settings? did you do the collect static?
try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12809416/django-static-files-404) in case

however, about serving static files in development:

> Warning This will only work if DEBUG is True.
>
> That’s because this view is **grossly inefficient and probably insecure**.
>   This is only intended for local development, and should never be used
>   in production.

from [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-in-development)

can't you just supply the static files in another server?

Comment: I'm sorry this was so long ago I can't remember. I think it stopped happening so I stopped worrying about it.

Comment: It's normal to serve static files from the dev server. It's typical for development. I didn't say this happens in production.

Answer (score -1):

After reading all answers if still anyone having this problem then ... 
As per Django nature you don't need to do anything to serve static files
just your settings file should have proper configuration as follows:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # **THIS IS USED WHEN YOUR STATIC FILES ARE IN SOME OTHER FOLDER ALSO**

    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.

    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.

    FOLDER_NAME, 
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    # other apps
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)
```

But if still you face problem put this into your `urls.py`:

**(r'^(path of your file)$', 'django.views.static.serve' , {'document_root': 'PROJECT_ROOT_DIR' + "path to the static folder"}),**

Above URL will serve for static files whether they are JS files or CSS or images.

In case of production server you don't need this.

Then run: `python manage.py collecstatic`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry this doesn't help. As per my question, this is an intermittent problem. Meaning: it works most of the time.

Comment: Thats what i wrote that by default you dont need to do anything to serve static files in your development environment. But if your facing it at irregular intervals , you can tweak it by this . hope this helps ..

Comment: Thank you, but I don't think this is the issue. It's probably around socket handling a bit lower down (i.e. to do with the Django code rather than the configuration of the file serving).