# Django gives "GET /static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0

Tags: python, html, css, django, django-staticfiles

ok so My

Index.html is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Kodeworms</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet"  href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/style.css" />
    </head>
    <body class="logged-out">
    </body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
.logged-out {
    background-image: href=("{{ STATIC_URL }}img/landing.jpg") no-repeat center 30px;
    background-size: 90%;
}
```

Now my index.html is stored in ***project_name/project_name/templates*** 
and my style.css is stored in ***project_name/assets/css*** 
and the image is stored in ***project_name/assets/img***

my setting.py is

```
# Django settings for BE.
import os

import dj_database_url

here = lambda * x: os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), *x)

PROJECT_ROOT = here("..")
root = lambda * x: os.path.join(os.path.abspath(PROJECT_ROOT), *x)

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': dj_database_url.config()
}

SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
# Hosts/domain names that are valid for this site; required if DEBUG is False
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['http://serene-schubland-8864.herokuapp.com']

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# In a Windows environment this must be set to your system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Calcutta'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale.
USE_L10N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not use timezone-aware datetimes.
USE_TZ = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/var/www/example.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = root("..","..", "uploads")

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://example.com/media/", "http://media.example.com/"
MEDIA_URL = ''

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/var/www/example.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = root("..","..", "static" )

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://example.com/static/", "http://static.example.com/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    root("..","assets"),
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = 'j%ox@teo++vyzqfjfr@4trs&cx&2q52)ss$+ds*u=(u+!k#b@i'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'BE.urls'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'BE.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    root("templates"),
)

DJANGO_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
)

THIRD_PARTY_APPS = (
    'south',
)

LOCAL_APPS = (
    'course',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = DJANGO_APPS + THIRD_PARTY_APPS + LOCAL_APPS

# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error when DEBUG=False.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

What Should I do to get the image load in background from css ?

Answer (score 24):

An HTTP 304 response means "I don't need to fetch it again, since it hasn't changed since I got it last". So if that's the response code you got, you may not have a problem at all. Or did you mean 404 (not found)?

In any event, you normally don't serve static files with Django directly; you do it through your front-end server. On Heroku, they have a special app and setup to help with that. You can read about it at: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets.

Also: you accidentally posted your SECRET_KEY in your message here. Please change that value to something else before you deploy or your site could have a serious security vulnerability. Keep that secret key a secret.

Comment: Now I'm getting this error `"GET /static/css/%7B%7B%20STATIC_URL%20%7D%7D/img/landing.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404`

Comment: Django isn't processing your CSS file, so Django template things like {{STATIC_URL}} aren't going to get changed in them. You could either change this to a relative-to-the-CSS-file URL (probably ../img/landing.jpg) or to a absolute-to-site-root URL (/static/img/landing.jpg).

Comment: Alright, this may have been an outdated question. But, just for additional information, I found the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12809416/django-static-files-404) to be useful in debugging the reference to the css file. Look at the comment by `deed02392` in the question. He mentioned to use: `python manage.py findstatic --verbosity 2 css/styles.css` and it helped me solve my problem. Just in case anyone came to the same problem with me.

Answer (score 2):

This could potentially be an issue when you do 
`{% load static %}` 
and then `{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}`.

When you call `{% load static %}`  it does it for you so you only need to specify the link to the static file you want dropping out the static nested within the href statement.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with **favicon.png**, just force browsers to update the cache by adding a GET parameter:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="{% static 'favicon.png' %}?ver=2"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem cuz I use {% load static %}   2-time in base.html and product.html(extent form base.html) so i remove {% load static %}   form product.html and i fix problem

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please make more obvious which addtional insight your post provides, especially in comparison to existing answers, which seem to already cover all the core points of this answer. Note that a different angle of explanation would already be such an additional insight, but I can't see anything here. Please do not expect users to find this post helpful.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).