# Django can't find static files on server

Tags: python, django

So I have this problem with deploying static files on server with Django. I am running nginx, and successfully tested my website locally, but now, when I'm deploying my site on the web, I can't load the local files, despite I have done everything according to the instructions. So I got this error all the time

```
"GET /staticold/botadd/anyfile HTTP/1.0" 404 99
```

My `settings.py` static settings looks like this

```
STATIC_URL = '/staticold/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'botadd/static'),
)
```

I've also tried it like this

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

`python manage.py collectfiles` command is successfull, all of my files are transfered to `STATIC_ROOT` folder, but then I got that 404 error. What can it be, I am stuck.

My `sites-available/default`

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #       # With php7.0-cgi alone:
    #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #       # With php7.0-fpm:
    #       fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #       deny all;
    #}
}
# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#       listen 80;
#       listen [::]:80;
#
#       server_name example.com;
#
#       root /var/www/example.com;
#       index index.html;
#
#       location / {
#               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#       }
#}
```

Comment: You might add your nginx config file as well as your urls.

Comment: Her you add `botadd` twice: one in the URL, and once in the `STATICFILES_DIRS`.

Comment: Not sure the problem is the config, but here it is

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem can you be more specific?

Comment: I meant the one in sites-enabled, where you configure your app server. Do you have nginx serve your static and media files or do you have django do that as you probably do locally?

Comment: @schwobaseggl yeah, probably, I haven't configured my sites-available

Comment: That is not the relevant nginx config. Where is the part where you a) proxy to your Django site and b) point to the static files?

Comment: @DanielRoseman just updated, can you check it out, please?

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12809416/django-static-files-404/17080877#17080877

Comment: @YogeshMhaskule it was for windows, didn't work for me

Comment: You probaly have your django app serve static files locally with the typical `DEBUG==True` switch in your urls. Now, on the server, where `debug==False`, django no longer serves the staic files, so have to configure nginx to serve them!

Comment: @JackAshton : You also need to add urlpatterns=+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) to your urls file. This will serve your static file. Other way to serve static files is through nginx file.

Comment: @AmarKamthe I've added this line to my project/urls.py, it didn't work

Comment: @JackAshton : Confirm that you have static root or static dirs one of them set to the static folder, not both of them.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to tell nginx where to look to serve your static content.  Try adding a "location /static/" block in your nginx sites-available file, eg:

```
server {
    server_name <your_server_name>.com;
    listen 443;
    listen [::]:443;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/private.key;
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        allow all;
        alias /your/base/dir/here/.../botadd/static/;
    }
    location / {
        ...
    }
}
```