# load picture from static file django

Tags: django

Django is not loading my static files. I'm trying to load an image from the static folder, but it doesn't work.

**file.html**

```
<body>

      {% load static %}
      <img src="{% static "products/logo.jpg" %}" alt="My image">
</body>
```

**structure**

```
app
|_______products
       |_________templates
                 |_________file.html
       |_________models.py
       |_________ ...

|______static
       |_________products
                 |_________logo.jpg
```

**settings**

```
...
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    ...
]

...

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django Static files 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12809416/django-static-files-404)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put this in your settings.py file:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>   
<head>
{% load static %}
</head>
<body>
<img src="{% static "products/logo.jpg" %}" alt="My image">
</body>
</html>
```

settings:

```
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [STATIC_DIR, ]
```