# Static files not loading on django localhost (404 error) while loading okay on heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

### Problem

I'm building a django web app. I can't get to display a static file (icon) in an html template when I run my app locally (ubuntu 20.04, python 3.8.5, django 3.1.4).

**I DO NOT HAVE THIS ISSUE WHEN DEPLOYING ON HEROKU CLOUD, only on my localhost.**
When loading up the webpabe on my localhost, I can see `"GET /static/icons/graph-up.svg HTTP/1.1" 404 1781` in the Django wsgi console.

**My project tree:**

```
django-project
|_ ...
|_ static
  |_ icons
    |_ graph-up.svg
```

**index.html**

```
{% load static %}
  <img src="{% static 'icons/graph-up.svg' %}" />
```

**settings.py**

```
[...]
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

# I've tried with and without whitenoise, doesnt seem to change anything
MIDDLEWARE = [
  # 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
  'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
  # ...
]

[...]
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [

    path('', views.home, name='index'),
    ...

] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

I've followed the instructions from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

Any ideas or suggestions welcome!

### What I've tried locally so far

**Without success (icon gets 404 error)**

- `python manage.py runserver` (to run with the wsgi from django)
- `gunicorn my_app.wsgi`
- `heroku local` (to simulate the heroku web server which is gunicorn locally)
- `python manage.py runserver --insecure` (from [Django Static files 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12809416/django-static-files-404))
- load the app locally with/without the `whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware` line in MIDDLEWARE after `django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware`

**With partial success**

Following an answer from [Django Static files 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12809416/django-static-files-404):

1. I replaced:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

with:

```
STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join('static'), )
```

2. I reloaded the wsgi and voila. The icon shows up.
3. **However** when I revert back to the original

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

Just to see what happens, the icon **still** shows up.

### Conclusion

I'm not sure this is the right thing to do but it seems to be working fine. Here's how I workaround the issue.

In my settings.py (for heroku):

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

In my settings_dev.py (for localhost):

```
STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join('static'), )
```

Comment: I am pretty sure heroku side, there is a `reverse proxy` for your djando app, while `python manage.py runserver` does not. if you can post your heroku config, that can help a bit.

Comment: cheers @tim - Heroku cloud runs gunicorn my_app.wsgi. I've tried to run my app locally with gunicorn too and I still have the same problem. Sorry forgot to mention that, editing my question now.

Comment: Hey @tamizboule were you able to figure out a solution for this? Facing the exact same issue. Static files work well on Heroku but not on my localhost

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what the problem is but to fix it you can use Whitenoise module, used to serve staticfiles

for Reference: https://youtu.be/kBwhtEIXGII

for in detail info.: http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/

Comment: thanks but i've tried with and without whitenoise and it doesnt seem to change anything