# Django App not reading static Javascript from <script>

Tags: javascript, python, django, static

Im fairly new at this and have been all through the previous answers but cant make this work. I am not getting django to read and apply my cart.js file from my base.html template. I have checked and rechecked my settings and files and just cant seem to find it. Can you help?

settings.py
[image]

base.html

[image]

static file structure

[image]

main urls.py

[image]

Error from template rendering

[image]

My best guess is it is somewhere in the static files settings but i just cant seem to understand where.

Answer (score 0):

Above script tag add

```
{% load static %}
```

Here's the documentation link of handling static files
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/

Comment: tried that before wasnt the issue

Answer (score 0):

Got it narrowed down at least. The issue is somewhere in WhiteNoise / STATICFILES_STORAGE
when you comment the line out everything works when you try including it, everything breaks

Answer link: [Other Post with the Same Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12809416/django-static-files-404?rq=1)

[image]

The issue seems to be in how WhiteNoise is storing and arranging files. Ive tested this through Heroku and everything still seems to be working fine without it although im not sure why.