# My html isn't connecting to my css only when running trought server

Tags: html, css, django

I am making a Django app and when I try to run the different pages the HTML is loading but not the CSS, when I open the files normally (not from the server) it all works fine, but when I run them through the server it searches for the CSS at the URL page. Here is an example:
at URL:http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/create/
the HTML is all working but CSS isn't and I get this in the terminal:

```
[21/Dec/2022 10:11:54] "GET /profile/create/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1374
Not Found: /profile/create/style.css
[21/Dec/2022 10:11:54] "GET /profile/create/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2993
```

The HTML and CSS are in the same directory and here is my connection from my HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>MyPlantApp</title>
</head>
```

Comment: You're not using Django features. Please follow the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/

Comment: @IvanStarostin tried with them aswell, doesent work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a folder for your static files and store all your static files there.

Set your static files directory using this code in your settings.py file:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")),
]
```

Your static folder should look like this [static file folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9VOz.png).

Also you need to use the proper templating syntax to specify find your static files. Change this:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">`

to this:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'static/style.css' %}">`

Comment: you should create the static folder in your project root directory

Comment: I tried all of that, still not loading it but the terminal output has change to
21/Dec/2022 10:36:33] "GET /profile/create/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1398
[21/Dec/2022 10:36:33] "GET /static/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1786

Comment: fixed it, and submited an edit to your post with what i did

Comment: if u specified the directory for the static files the way i posted i don't think u need to make the edit u added. while stating your base directory did u add a forward slash?

Comment: i made it: static 'style/style.css'

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting `/` before `style.css`?
You are trying to get style.css from relative path of HTML file.
If u put / before `style.css` it will try to get css file from root directory.

`/style.css` instead of `style.css`

```html
<!-- Your Code -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<!-- Might help -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css">
```

Comment: tried, sadly didnt work, ty for the help tho

Comment: Looks like someone found the solution, but it might help too.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17080877/14098917
Good luck!